# Trimming ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion

I used this command to trim the video:

"ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -to 00:06:49 -c copy out1.ts
ffmpeg -ss 00:07:13 -i input.mp4 -c copy out2.ts
ffmpeg -i 'concat:out1.ts|out2.ts' -c copy output3.mp4"

This command works, but it causes the video to freeze for about 1 second wherever I trim it. I have attached a video below to provide an example of the freeze frame issue.

example : https://jumpshare.com/v/r510dpNflKUFJEFXQXlP

Answer (score 1):

You are probably not cutting the video on top of key frames while using the copy option what keeps the same video codec.

A solution would be to render the video by specifying a video codec in the -c option or make the cut on top of a key frame.

To check where the key frames are you can use this command:

```
ffprobe -loglevel error -skip_frame nokey -select_streams v:0 -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time -of csv=print_section=0 input.mp4
```

Comment: I have tried these commands, but nothing seems to work. I am still experiencing the freeze frame issue. I can't paste it here because it's too long. Here is the Pastebin link instead.
 https://pastebin.com/tjGp7gAy